# ASP.Net get columns with values, add them and then divide

Tags: asp.net, average

I've got some code which is working as it should but it just seems like a bit of a round about way in doing it and wondered if anyone had any ideas of how to tidy it up

Here's my code

```
Dim TotalNumber As Double

    Dim NumberFilled As String

    NumberFilled = Nothing

    For x = 0 To drCode2a.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1

        If Not drCode2a.Tables(0).Rows(0)(x).ToString() = "0" Then

            NumberFilled += drCode2a.Tables(0).Rows(0)(x).ToString() & "-"

            TotalNumber = TotalNumber + drCode2a.Tables(0).Rows(0)(x).ToString()

        End If
    Next

    Dim delimiters As Char() = New Char() {"-"c}

    Dim TotalNumberFilled As String() = NumberFilled.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim AverageRating As Double = TotalNumber / TotalNumberFilled.Length

Response.Write(NumberFilled & "<br/>" & TotalNumber & "<br/>" & AverageRating)
```

Basically for my example `NumberFilled = "1-2-"` and `TotalNumber = 3` and `AverageRating = 1.5`

It shows that 2 columns were filled out and the total they equal is 3 so the average = 1.5

As I said it works like it should but I'd like to tidy up if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim totalNumber as Double = 0
Dim count as Integer = 0

For x = 0 To drCode2a.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
  Dim current as Double = 0
  If Double.TryParse(drCode2a.Tables(0).Rows(0)(x).ToString(), current) AndAlso current <> 0 Then
    count += 1
    totalNumber += current
  End If
Next

Dim averageRating as Double = totalNumber / count
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative. I don't know that it's necessarily better, but it does make use of the `StringBuilder` object which is a little faster than strings and it keeps the total values as doubles rather than performing double to string to double conversions.

```
Dim NumberFilled As New StringBuilder("")
Dim TotalNumber as Double
Dim ColumnsFilled as Integer = 0

For each column as DataColumn in drCode2a.Tables(0).Columns
    Dim value = drCode2a.Tables(0).Rows(0)(column.ColumnName).ToString()
    If Not "0".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

        If NumberFilled.Length > 0 Then NumberFilled.Append("-")
        NumberFilled.Append(value)
        TotalNumber = Convert.ToDouble(value)
        ColumnsFilled += 1

    End If
Next
```